# I don't know how to use life cycle in svelte.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, svelte

## Assumptions

I don't know much about the front end.

## wants to do

I want to use life cycle with sveltejs.

## Error occurred

The following error has occurred and the lifecycle method is not available:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/svelte/index.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './internal' in 'C:\project\test_svelte_lifecycle\node_modules\svelte'
 @ ./node_modules/svelte/index.mjs 1:0-167 1:0-167 1:0-167 1:0-167 1:0-167 1:0-167 1:0-167 1:0-167 1:0-167 1:0-167
 @ ./test-component.svelte
 @ ./app.js
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

What is the cause of this?

I got this code from the formula.
However, an error occurred and it did not work.
I don't know why.

A person with the same error made a github issue.

https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2937

I modified my code accordingly, but it didn't work.

## code

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "svelte": "^3.17.2",
    "svelte-loader": "^2.13.6",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "svelte": "^3.17.2"
  }
}
```

---

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app.js'),

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            svelte: path.resolve('node_modules', 'svelte')
        },
        extensions: ['.svelte'],
        mainFields: ['svelte', 'browser', 'module', 'main']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(html|svelte)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'svelte-loader',
                    options: {
                        customElement: true
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

---

**test-component.svelte**

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  let hello = "hello";
  let world = "world";

  onMount(async () => {
    hello = "hello hello";
  });
</script>

<svelte:options tag="test-component" />

<div>{hello} and {world}</div>
```

---

**app.js**

```js
import TestComponent from './test-component.svelte';
```

---

**index.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <test-component></test-component>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think your error is not related to lifecycle but rather to the bundler and module imports. Have you tried to create a simple component and import it in your main component, just to see if the project will build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your error is because you don't have `.mjs` in your webpack's `resolve.extensions`. The file singled out by the error message `./internal` is actually a `.mjs` file, but you only have `.svelte` extensions...

It should be something like this:

```js
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      svelte: path.resolve('node_modules', 'svelte'),
    },
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.svelte'],
    mainFields: ['svelte', 'browser', 'module', 'main'],
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.As you said, it can now compile webpack.config by adding code!
Thank you.